# Standard for electrical schematics in the UK

Tags: circuit-design, schematics, control-system

I'm trying to find out whether there is an accepted standard for electrical schematics in the UK. From my research so far, I've come across IEC 60617 however this appears to have been withdrawn. I also found this post on the IET website (https://communities.theiet.org/discussions/viewtopic/348/20012) which states the following but I'm not clear what is meant by *"the database"*.

> IEC 60617 contains graphical symbols for use in electrotechnical diagrams. All the parts (Ed. 2 or 3) of the previously published IEC 60617 have been incorporated into this database that currently includes some 1900 symbols. The database is the official source of IEC 60617.

Is IEC 60617 the de facto standard for electrical schematics in the UK or is there another standard? The area I'm specifically interested in is schematics for industrial control panels.